# Inserting data from Coinbase API V2 into a MySQL Database using php

Tags: php, mysql, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I'm a bit stuck here. I'm building an app based on the Coinbase PHP API V2.

This is what I'm trying to achieve. I would like to place the currency code (for e.g. EUR or USD) and the corresponding sell price at the moment of calling in my local MySQL database (ideal also including a timestamp).

I'm getting this info by using the method: getSellPrice(). This method returns this info:

```
Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money Object ( [amount:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] => 2250.47 [currency:Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money:private] => USD )
```

So far so good. But how do I get these values saved in my database? Breaking it down I have the following sub-questions:

1. How do extract the values "amount=>2250.47" and "currency=>USD"?
2. How do I save these 2 values in the corresponding columns "amount" and "currency" in my database?
3. What exact script do I need /steps to follow?

Just some general info. I'm using XAMPP as local server.

This is the code which I have so far:

`

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;

//Connect with credentials.
$apiKey = 'xxx';
$apiSecret = 'xxx';

$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);

$client = Client::create($configuration);

$sellPrice = $client->getSellPrice('BTC-USD');
print_r ($sellPrice);

//So far it works fine.

?>
```

`

I have set up a table by using this query:

```
`CREATE TABLE `data` (
`id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`time_stamp` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`currency` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
`amount` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) 
);
```

`

Every help is welcome or pointing me in the right direction. And is much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is a method, which gets you the response in a raw format.

Check out `$data = $client->decodeLastResponse();`

It's taken from the original [documentation](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php#responses) on git.

Comment: Ah great man! Thanks a lot. By using decodeLastResponse() it puts it in an array. Which is a lot easier to handle! :)

Answer (score 0):

TRY This code to get amount and currency

```
$sellPrice = $client->getSellPrice('BTC-USD');
$amount=$sellPrice->getAmount();                                
$currency=$sellPrice->getCurrency();
```

Hope it will work